# <optgroup> functionality in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist, selectoption

Good day everyone,

I want to create a select in salesforce which look is similar to html tag **optgroup**. I want create an option within an option. Is it possible ? If yes, how will I do it ?

Thanks...

Comment: HTML tags are also supported in VF so you can try optgroup and then using Javascript remoting or action function you can pass the selected value in controller.

Comment: @TusharSharma This is a good suggestion but the problem is that this strategy doesn't fit my requirements. Do you have any idea how to make it in apex class ?

Comment: try map<string,List<string>> then in the key part put your label and in value put all your option. it will give you same layout.